# "Doon the watter" in Glasgow

Tags: scotland, riverboats, rivers, glasgow

I shall be going to Glasgow with my family this summer and I would like to take them on the traditional cruise "Doon the watter" (Down the river) on the [Waverley steamer](http://www.waverleyexcursions.co.uk/) or similar. There are many different excursions to different parts of the clyde coast, lochs and islands, however I have never gone doon the watter before myself even though I come from Glasgow. Which tour would be recommended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are starting from Largs then I would suggest going across to Brodick, on Arran, or from Wemyss Bay to Rothesay, on Bute, as both these destinations offer not only a nice cruise, but plenty to do when you get there. They can give a great day out for all age groups - my father in law recently took my kids on the Bute day trip, and they had a great time.

If you have more time and can afford to stay over in various locations, a great cruise would take you first to Rothesay, then Tighnabruich, Tarbert and along Loch Fyne and Arran.

Check out [visitbute.com](http://www.visitbute.com/) and [visitarran.com](http://www.visitarran.com/site/arranactivities.aspx).

Remember the weather can be exceedingly changeable, so plan for wet and sunny - waterproofs, layers and sun screen.